# Relation of fluctuation in density measurement with volume

Tags: condensed-matter, density

I read in this [paper](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.1140414):

"... a region of volume V, with N particles on average , ordinarily shows fluctuations with standard deviation $\Delta N$ proportional to $\sqrt{N}$, so that the fluctuation in the number density go down as $1/\sqrt{V}$."

Why is the fluctuation in number of particles proportional to $\sqrt{N}$? And how does the fluctuation in number density go down as $1/\sqrt{V}$?

How can I derive these two statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is mostly a statement about the choice of probability distribution rather than the physics itself. The author is implicitly assuming that the particle number in the volume $V$ is picked from a poisson distribution. A poisson distribution has the following form:

$$ P(N;\mu) = e^{-\mu} \frac{\mu^N}{N!}$$

where $N$ is the number of particles and $\mu$ is the average number of particles.
This works quite well if the events (in this case number of particles) are independent and the number density is quite low. Using this it is quite straightforward to show that the standard deviation is proportional to $\sqrt{\mu}$ which for a fixed volume is equivalent to $\sqrt{NV}$. Therefore the fluctuations in the number density grow as

$$ \Delta n = \frac{\Delta N}{V} \sim \frac{\sqrt{V}}{V} \sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}$$

Comment: I see, the Poisson distribution is the reason why, I should have anticipated this. Thanks.